# Methods on descriptors

Tags: python, redis

I'm trying to implement a wrapper around a redis database that does some bookkeeping, and I thought about using descriptors. I have an object with a bunch of fields: frames, failures, etc., and I need to be able to **get**, **set**, and increment the field as needed. I've tried to implement an Int-Like descriptor:

```py
class IntType(object):
    def __get__(self,instance,owner):
        # issue a GET database command
        return db.get(my_val)

    def __set__(self,instance,val):
        # issue a SET database command
        db.set(instance.name,val)

    def increment(self,instance,count):
        # issue an INCRBY database command
        db.hincrby(instance.name,count)

class Stream:
    _prefix = 'stream'
    frames = IntType()
    failures = IntType()
    uuid = StringType()

s = Stream()

s.frames.increment(1)  # float' object has no attribute 'increment'
```

Is seems like I can't access the increment() method in my descriptor. I  can't have increment be defined in the object that the __get__ returns. This would require an additional db query if all I want to do is increment! I also don't want increment() on the Stream class, as later on when I want to have additional fields like strings or sets in Stream, then I'd need to type check the heck out of everything.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
class Stream:
    _prefix = 'stream'

    def __init__(self):
        self.frames = IntType()
        self.failures = IntType()
        self.uuid = StringType()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class IntType(object):
    def __get__(self,instance,owner):
        class IntValue():

            def increment(self,count):
                # issue an INCRBY database command
                db.hincrby(self.name,count)

            def getValue(self):
                # issue a GET database command
                return db.get(my_val)

        return IntValue()

   def __set__(self,instance,val):
       # issue a SET database command
       db.set(instance.name,val)
```

Comment: Calling increment still results in 2 queries: db.get, and db.hincrby

Comment: Ok, I will amend this

Comment: if I needed to explicitly add a getValue() then this almost defeats the purpose of using descriptors to start with.

Comment: Well, I didn't wanted to say that but I think you should not use descriptors, if you want complete control over the db access you should wrap your results in a proper object. I was just trying to adapt to your decision of using descriptors. With my proposal, yes, you need an extra call for the get but, as you wanted, there is no extra db access for the increment plus the set is transparent (so descriptor is still playing a role!) You need a decision: an extra call for the get or an extra db access, for me is simple, now you make your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Why not define the magic method **iadd** as well as **get** and **set**. This will allow you to do normal addition with assignment on the class. It will also mean you can treat the increment separately from the get function and thereby minimise the database accesses.

So change:

```
    def increment(self,instance,count):
        # issue an INCRBY database command
        db.hincrby(instance.name,count)
```

to:

```
    def __iadd__(self,other):
        # your code goes here
```

Comment: This would be nice, but it's a one-off solution. Increment is an atomic operation, and it's not quite an add. Say later on, I want to add SetType, with methods like set_add, set_intersect, etc. There's no corresponding builtins for those types.

Comment: So just to be clear, the reason the increment is not working in your orignial code is because you have implemented the get magic method and so when you try to dereference your object to call increment you instead call teh get and get its result rather than the object itself. Hence the reson you are seeing it complain that float does not have a increment method. It sounds like the very specific and narrowinterface given by a descriptor is not what you actually need here. If that is the case then you will need to stop overloading get and use different names for the get and set functions.